# Confusing status on virtualbox+fabric8/kubernetes+docker

Tags: docker, windows-7, virtualbox, kubernetes, fabric8

Iam start working with fabric8 for some days now. And I have some confusing issues here.

Windows7 + VirtualBox + Fabric8 + Docker -are installed and "running"

- After starting fabric8 (gofabric8 start --vm-driver=virtualbox) everything starts, but the **console is not available**. status: running and N/A
- My Minikube cluster is shuting down sometime by its own (seems
  like)
- After "gofabric8 docker-env" and the FOR Loop. Docker Images showed me some stuff and I started to install with mvn but it failed on docker.
- Now I have a real weird status: the status of the kubes shows me: stopped and N/A ... **BUT the fabric8 console is still available and working** -.-

OK ... Iam new to this stuff but and still dont get the whole system in my mind. But until now I always had the right idea to continue. Now Iam lost at that point.

Hope someone can share me some experience for that.

Comment: What is the question? Also, you says things like "shutting down sometime by its own" and "showed me some stuff". What stuff? How do you know it is shutting down? You need to provide some logs and commands you are using to test.

Comment: Sorry for that confusing post. I tried to ask several quastions at once I guess.
The main problem is that I still have read some docs.

But the question here is why my pods or nodes are shutting down by their own?

Comment: OK, but that also sounds like two separate questions (nodes shutting down vs pods failing). Can you clarify the question to ask this and maybe give some output from `kubectl describe pod <pod_you_have_issues_with>`?

Answer (score 0):

Further info:

```
 C:\dev>kubectl describe pod springboottut
    Name:           springboottut-1940958062-mfxlj
    Namespace:      default
    Node:           minikube/192.168.99.100
    Start Time:     Tue, 23 May 2017 20:01:35 +0200
    Labels:         group=net.sklorz
                    pod-template-hash=1940958062
                    project=springboottut
                    provider=fabric8
                    version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    Annotations:    fabric8.io/metrics-path=dashboard/file/kubernetes-pods.json/?var-project=springboottut&var-version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
                    fabric8.io/scm-tag=HEAD
                    fabric8.io/scm-url=https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/springboottut
                    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"springboottut-1940
    958062","uid":"dc4e9aa9-3fe1-11e7-8fb6-0800271...
    Status:         Running
    IP:             172.17.0.12
    Controllers:    ReplicaSet/springboottut-1940958062
    Containers:
      spring-boot:
        Container ID:       docker://d96f2a2313bb7049cd5bb63568e2e01f1484827965843e73f7dbf94d76d61006
        Image:              sklorz/springboottut:snapshot-170523-200054-0346
        Image ID:           docker://sha256:cb5b28e95c9bd0ecb16ee3d9a0d39ab320ae0a896a598339285a7061ad504c94
        Ports:              8080/TCP, 9779/TCP, 8778/TCP
        State:              Running
          Started:          Tue, 23 May 2017 20:01:37 +0200
        Ready:              True
        Restart Count:      0
        Liveness:           http-get http://:8080/health delay=180s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
        Readiness:          http-get http://:8080/health delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
        Environment:
          KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE:     default (v1:metadata.namespace)
        Mounts:
          /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-fwls2 (ro)
    Conditions:
      Type          Status
      Initialized   True
      Ready         True
      PodScheduled  True
    Volumes:
      default-token-fwls2:
        Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
        SecretName: default-token-fwls2
        Optional:   false
    QoS Class:      BestEffort
    Node-Selectors: <none>
    Tolerations:    <none>
    Events:
      FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubObjectPath                   Type            Reason          Message
      ---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------                   --------        ------          -------
      50m           50m             1       default-scheduler                                       Normal          Scheduled       Successfully assigned springboottut-194095
    8062-mfxlj to minikube
      50m           50m             1       kubelet, minikube       spec.containers{spring-boot}    Normal          Pulled          Container image "sklorz/springboottut:snap
    shot-170523-200054-0346" already present on machine
      50m           50m             1       kubelet, minikube       spec.containers{spring-boot}    Normal          Created         Created container with id d96f2a2313bb7049
    cd5bb63568e2e01f1484827965843e73f7dbf94d76d61006
      50m           50m             1       kubelet, minikube       spec.containers{spring-boot}    Normal          Started         Started container with id d96f2a2313bb7049
    cd5bb63568e2e01f1484827965843e73f7dbf94d76d61006
```

Its running right now.
Now I still need to find out how to access the REST-API in that pod... 
(3rd questsion :) )

Comment: Its running.. But:
`C:\dev>gofabric8 status
minikubeVM: Stopped
localkube: N/A`

Thats what confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Some solutions I find for my self:

- The HyperV on Win7 worked at last. (This is why I had two clusters
  running - a virtualbox and a HyperV one)
- Try setup Kubernetes using    their getting started docs(minikube)
  before setup fabric8 (gofabric8)    it makes things clearer.
- Setup Docker and using 'gofabric8    docker-env' and the FOR LOOP is
  neccessary but not mentoined often in    the docs.
- Bottom line I wanted the maven fabric8 plugin running, so    focusing
  on using their goal and docs at last lead me to the right
  direction.

Open issues:

- Cant access the deployed Project in the cluster. Guess I need to
  setup proxies next.
- The maven fabric8 plugin dont work seamlessly with Docker env. Need
  to investigate.

Hope I can help some other who have similar problems. And Iam still glad about any hints given :)